# make 2D array in C# and show in text box

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I want to display a matrix as shown below in a textbox, but I don't know where to start. How can I get this result in a textbox?

```
 5  5  5  5
 8  9  3  1
 7  9  2  7 
 3  7  8  6
 8  3  1  2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have no idea what you talking about. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: i want show 2D array in text box

Comment: You can probably get that by assigning it to a `TextBox.Text`. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[,] matrix = new int[,] {{5, 5, 5, 5},
                            {8, 9, 3, 1},
                            {7, 9, 2, 7},
                            {3, 7, 8, 6},
                            {8, 3, 1, 2}};
```

You will need to create a multiline `TextBox` to show this information. Then use something like this to write the matrix to the `TextBox`:

```
string matrixString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        matrixString += matrix[i, j].ToString();
        matrixString += " ";
    }

    matrixString += Environment.NewLine;
}
this.textBoxName.Text = matrixString;
```

You get this result:

[image: Result]

Comment: @user3477496 Opps. You're right. I edited the post to make it more accurate. Hopefully it will work now. (I was thinking of the HTML `textarea`, sorry).

Comment: your code it doesn't work.because this line (for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; i++)) and this line (matrixString += matrix[i][j].ToString() + ", ";)

Comment: I got this code to work for me. Let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: this code is work but The previous code did not work.tnx so much for your helping...